# Do implementations of the Web Audio API tend to make full use of available CPU cores?

Tags: javascript, multiprocessing, web-audio-api

A somewhat general question, and I am interested in answers pertaining to any and all browsers with Web Audio API support.

If I make use of a large number of AudioNodes in a web audio application, are implementations of the Web Audio API share processing across the available cores of a machine (e.g. by perhaps assigning part of the node 'graph' to each core)?

The only reference to Web Audio multi-core support I could find was at https://padenot.github.io/web-audio-perf/, which just says that multi-core support should be used for `decodeAudioData`.

Answer (score 1):

Most implementations will put the audio system on a separate core from most of the rest of the web platform (e.g. JavaScript execution and layout) but it won't split across multiple cores for separate nodes. (The API would have to expose that, since it would increase latency.)